# XML Selection based

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
  <aa>
        <abc>
            <name>convention</name>
            <value>test1</value>
        </abc>
        <abc>
            <name>computer</name>
            <value>test2</value>
        </abc>
        <abc>
            <name>human</name>
            <value>test3</value>
        </abc>
        <abc>
            <name>airplane</name>
            <value>test4</value>
        </abc>
        <abc>
            <name>flight</name>
            <value>test5</value>
        </abc>
        <abc>
            <name>keyboard</name>
            <value>test6</value>
        </abc>
    </aa>
```

I want to select one of the values for the name based on selection. For e.g. if name is flight then I need to select it's value test5. And don't display all, only display the value for name flight. How do we do this ?

Edit: Sorry to not mention the language.

I'm using an xlst on the above xml to select and get only the value of flight for example.

I tried this:

```
   <xsl:variable name="test" select="/aa/abc[@name='flight']"/>
   <Test name= "{$test}"/>
```

But this doesn't seem to fetch the value for flight.

Comment: Without further editing to provide more context, no member of this community is going to be able to provide you with a quality answer for this question. Please edit your question to let us know what environment/programming language you are using, and what wrong answers you have found in your search for a solution to your problem.

Comment: @RyanRansford: Thanks I made the edit and added more information.

Comment: @Mike: I tried this, as mentioned by JLRishe below. It displays as: flight test5. I just want to display test5. How do I do that ?

Comment: /aa/abc[name = 'flight']/value - should do it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `name` is an element and not an attribute, the `@` is incorrect. Please try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="/aa/abc[name='flight']/value"/>
<Test name="{$test}"/>
```

Comment: This is giving me the name and it's value in one shot. e.g:flight test5. I just want to select test5 and don't want to display flight.

Comment: In that case, you need to select the value element. Please see my modification above.

Comment: Thanks buddy that sorted out. Learnt something out of it. Thank to you. Great help. Take care.